# Possible to run PyCharm CE's Python debugger on a Python script that's run from the command line?

Tags: pycharm

I have a Python script that requires command-line arguments.  Is it possible to use the PyCharm CE Python debugger in this situation, or must I resort to a litany of print statements?

Glad to clarify as needed, still learning about appropriate level of detail for posts like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify command line arguments in Parameters field in the run configuration for the given script

[image]

Run configurations can be created via **Run | Edit Configurations** menu or by right-clicking the script -> More Run/Debug -> Modify Run Configuration

[image]